# Unable to generate karma.conf in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am practicing CI/CD and started to configure karma.conf. However, I found that Angular projects no longer have karma.conf, and the official recommendation "ng generate config karma" doesn't work and gives me the following error: "Error: Unknown argument: karma". How can I resolve this issue?

Thank any help!

Here is my version information:

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.5
Node: 19.7.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 15.2.1
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.1
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.5
@angular/cli                    15.0.5
@schematics/angular             15.0.5
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

Yes, here are my package.json, please.

```
{
  "name": "unitest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your package.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update your angular version and run

```js
ng g config karma
```

tested in angular 15.2.2 and it successfully generated

```js
{
  "name": "ang-testing-poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, it worked! It seems that it was indeed an issue with the Angular version. Thank you so much for sharing your solution.